# Display Custom Block Content

Tags: blocks, theming

I would like to know the proper way to display content of a block.
So far, i know a few ways:

1) Output html directly to block content. ie. $block['content'] = 'Hello';

2) Using preprocess and theme function and output variable to template file.

3) Provide an array to the block content. ie.

```
  $block = array(

'contact' => array(      
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => 'some content here',
)

 );
```

I am still new to drupal, can someone tell me about the pros and cons of using above methods?

or is there other way to do it?

Comment: Hello and welcome. By custom block, do you mean a block created in your module, or added by hand, using Drupal's GIU? If the first one, have you seen [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples)?

Comment: @Mołot , yes, i did check the Example module. The block example is using renderable array. In term of performance (which one is cache friendly, etc) , which method above is better?

Comment: If in doubt, always use methods from examples, both examples project and examples from api docs. That's what they are for. Unless you have a good reason not to do it, of course.